# Not Implemented Error: Exception encountered building CNN-LSTM model in Tensorflow 2.9

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

This is a code snippet for building a cnn-lstm with pre-trained mobilenet encoder head.

```
inputs = Input(shape = (60, 224, 224, 3))
cnn_base = MobileNetV3Small(include_top = False, weights='imagenet', input_shape = (224, 224, 3))

cnn_out = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(cnn_base.output)
cnn = Model(inputs=cnn_base.input, outputs=cnn_out)
cnn_out.set_shape((None, 576))
encoded_frames = TimeDistributed(cnn)(inputs)
encoded_sequence = LSTM(256)(encoded_frames)

hidden_layer = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(encoded_sequence)
outputs = Dense(50, activation="softmax")(hidden_layer)
model = Model([inputs], outputs)
```

I have been getting this error:

```
NotImplementedError: Exception encountered when calling layer "time_distributed_43" (type TimeDistributed).

Please run in eager mode or implement the `compute_output_shape` method on your layer (TFOpLambda).

Call arguments received by layer "time_distributed_43" (type TimeDistributed):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 60, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32)
  • training=False
  • mask=None
```

Does anyone know any quick fix to this? I have already tried using eager execution but no luck with:

```
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked. The quick simple trick is:

```
input_layer = Inputs(...)
...
lstm_in = Lambda(lambda x: whatever_cnn_model(x))
lstm_input = TimeDistributed(lstm_in, input_shape=[sequence input shape])(input_layer)
```